# Setting values to NA based on other variable

Tags: r

I'm doing analyses and am getting some doubtful results. However, one of my variables is not normally distributed. To check if this is the problem, I've tried to create a new, normally distributed variable that has the same mean and standard deviation as the original.

However, the original also has a lot of NAs, which I also want to mirror in my new variable (so that I can be certain that any differences between the original and the new variable can be attributed to the normal nature of the variable).

I've tried several ways to do it, but keep getting the warning that "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".

Can anyone help me? Below is the code I used to create a new variable!

```
data$var_normal <- rnorm(data$var_original, mean = 0.6200154, sd = 0.3555574)
```

And basically what I want to do:

```
if(data$var_original==NA) data$var_normal <- NA
```

Comment: Try `data$var_normal <- ifelse(is.na(data$var_original), NA, data$var_normal) `

Comment: Maybe `is.na(data$var_normal) <- is.na(data$var_original)`.

Comment: I've tried the first one and it is solved now, thanks!